# Working for a US-based company in Canada as an American citizen

Tags: usa, working-visas, canada

My SO and I are contemplating moving to Toronto soon (within the next year or two) and I was curious as to what the process/restrictions/tax liability would be for us.

I am currently a software engineer at a NYC based company and my SO would be a student, possibly at the University of Toronto if all works out. I'd like to continue working for this current company remotely from Toronto while she is in school, perhaps becoming permanent residents later.

Things I've explored so far:

1. Began completion of the skilled worker application but not completed because we both need to take the English language test.
2. It sounds like (from others' experience) I may need to become a contractor similar to one of my coworkers who is Serbian.
3. My salary in USD is more than enough to continue to support us both while she is in school.

Questions I still have:

1. What are the tax implications of remaining an employee of a US company in Canada?
2. What are the visa requirements for me as skilled worker?

P.S. I have explored similar questions but they frequently contain circumstances which differ greatly from mine e.g. different citizenship status, already a contractor etc.

Comment: I will gently suggest that you'll have more success here by focusing on one question at a time. All in all, this is much too broad: one could write lengthy essays on each of your numbers 1, 2, and 3. You might review this Expatriates Help page: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask to assist you in crafting appropriate questions, remembering that this is not a discussion board, doesn't welcome opinions, but instead provides a way of asking specific questions that generate definitive answers.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica okay I'll revise

Answer (score 1):

> "What are the tax implications of remaining an employee of a US company in Canada?

If you become a [tax resident of Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/international-non-residents/individuals-leaving-entering-canada-non-residents/factual-residents-temporarily-outside-canada.html) then, as far as I am aware , you can not be employed by a US company. In very broad strokes, employee as a concept only works domestically in general everywhere. You'd need to become a contractor or you company would need a Canadian subsidiary or you could use a Global Employment Organization (GEO). Most of us in similar situations just become contractors.

Comment: Yeah I think contractor is the way to go then. Do you have any insight to the second question about visa requirements as a contractor?

Comment: As suggested above: separate your questions. The visa problem is a different bag of hurt and one that you likely find insurmountable but I am not 100% on this because I am not American and there might be special provisions for Americans. If there aren't, skilled worker visa (without Express Entry which is clearly out of question) takes many years to process.

Comment: I'll create a new question, but I've actually already started the Express Entry application after it was determined that I qualify.